Email alert when specific sheet is edited - Google Sheets
I am having trouble refining a script to only send an email when any text is entered into a specific sheet (named "Washouts") and that text is carried over by another script (mergeAndClearRows(), below), not manually entered.
It currently is sending an email when any text is entered in any cell, on any & all of my tabs instead of restricting to only the "Washouts" sheet.
function sendEmailOnEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = "Washouts"; // Sheet Name
  var sheet = e?.source?.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  if (sheet) {
    var range = e.range;
    var editedValue = range.getValue();

    // Check if any text (non-empty) is entered
    if (editedValue !== "") {
      // Tailor message
      var message = 'Text entered in the Washouts sheet: ' + editedValue;
      var subject = 'message body alert';

      // Email entry
      var recipientEmail = 'myemailaddyhere';

      // Send the email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message);
    }
  }
}

This is the script I am using, and have modified close to 50 times with the same result. It is not restricting the edits to the Washouts sheet, even with the manual trigger set correctly.
Basically a checkbox is checked if a truck required a washout, when checked, the row is clicked, menu item "complete load" is clicked, and the row is carried then to 2 other sheets instead of just the "completed loads" tab. It is then also carried over to the "washouts" tab as a duplicate. This all works fine, but I want it to send me an email when someone sends the copy over to the "washouts" tab so I can be made aware.
Everything is working other than it is sending an email whenever any cell is entered on any of the sheets.
function mergeAndClearRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // Checkbox column is currently U (adjust if I do move to the end)
  var checkboxValue = rowValues[0][20]; // Column U (index 20)
  
  // Initialize destValues array
  // need to adjust later to slim down washout copies, not sure how yet without extending script run time.
  var destValues = [
    rowValues[0][0], rowValues[0][1], rowValues[0][2], rowValues[0][3],
    rowValues[0][4], rowValues[0][5], rowValues[0][6], rowValues[0][7],
    rowValues[0][8], rowValues[0][9], rowValues[0][10], rowValues[0][11],
    rowValues[0][12], rowValues[0][13], rowValues[0][14], rowValues[0][15],
    rowValues[0][16], rowValues[0][19]
    // Add more values as needed
  ];
  
  // second copy for washouts if box is checked
  if (checkboxValue === true) {
    var destWashouts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Washouts');
    destWashouts.getRange(destWashouts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
    
    // Set value column Q
    sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 17).setValue(false);
  }
  
  // Completed Loads if U = false
  var destCompletedLoads = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed Loads');
  destCompletedLoads.getRange(destCompletedLoads.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
  
  // Clear content
  var rangeToClear = sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 9, 1, 7);
  rangeToClear.clearContent();
  
  // Clear U
  sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 21).setValue(false);
  
  // Clear content in column T (index 20) regardless of checkbox status
  sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 20).clearContent();
}


e.source returns the spreadsheet where the event has taken place - the spreadsheet, not the sheet. So the line:
var sheet = e?.source?.getSheetByName("Washouts");

; is the same as doing:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Washouts");

In other words, you're accessing that sheet whether the event took place in it or not.
To access the sheet where the event took place, you can use e.range.getSheet(), and then getName() to get its name. You just need to check that it is indeed the correct one.
So, to sum up, the sendEmailOnEdit function can be modified as follows1:
function sendEmailOnEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();  // <-- Changed this line...
  
  if (sheetName === "Washouts") {  // <-- ...and this line.
    var range = e.range;
    var editedValue = range.getValue();

    // Check if any text (non-empty) is entered
    if (editedValue !== "") {
      // Tailor message
      var message = 'Text entered in the Washouts sheet: ' + editedValue;
      var subject = 'message body alert';

      // Email entry
      var recipientEmail = 'myemailaddyhere';

      // Send the email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message);
    }
  }
}

1EDIT - This answer is incomplete, and will not work in this case. Please see @ELSRY 's answer.
References

Event objects


Providing more information on how to integrate the answer of @user27425627 to your requirements.
Although, the answer is making a restriction for the OnEdit() to only be possible to the “Washouts” sheet. The data is being transferred by another script is practically not possible to trigger the onEdit event since Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. (see Simple Trigger Restrictions for more information). However, you can force the OnEdit() behavior by passing a custom event object to make the code work (sending an email whenever the data is passed by a script).
Modified code in the mergeAndClearRows():
 // second copy for washouts if box is checked
 if (checkboxValue === true) {
   var destWashouts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Washouts');
   destWashouts.getRange(destWashouts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
  
   var fakeEvent = {
     range: destWashouts.getRange(destWashouts.getLastRow(), 1, 1, destValues.length),
     value: destValues[0]
   };
   sendEmailOnEdit(fakeEvent);


   // Set value column Q
   sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 17).setValue(false);
 }

NOTE: I have proposed this code in case you have another purpose on why you need OnEdit() on your code. However, if you only need the sendEmailOnEdit(e) to send the email whenever the data is transferred to the “Washouts” sheet, you can simply chain methods to your condition to send an email as well if the value of checkbox is set to TRUE and should be copied to the said sheet.
Complete updated code:
function mergeAndClearRows() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
 var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
 var rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  // Checkbox column is currently U (adjust if I do move to the end)
 var checkboxValue = rowValues[0][20]; // Column U (index 20)
  // Initialize destValues array
 var destValues = [
   rowValues[0][0], rowValues[0][1], rowValues[0][2], rowValues[0][3],
   rowValues[0][4], rowValues[0][5], rowValues[0][6], rowValues[0][7],
   rowValues[0][8], rowValues[0][9], rowValues[0][10], rowValues[0][11],
   rowValues[0][12], rowValues[0][13], rowValues[0][14], rowValues[0][15],
   rowValues[0][16], rowValues[0][19]
 ];
  // second copy for washouts if box is checked
 if (checkboxValue === true) {
   var destWashouts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Washouts');
   destWashouts.getRange(destWashouts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
  
   var fakeEvent = {
     range: destWashouts.getRange(destWashouts.getLastRow(), 1, 1, destValues.length),
     value: destValues[0]
   };
   sendEmailOnEdit(fakeEvent);


   // Set value column Q
   sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 17).setValue(false);
 }
  // Completed Loads if U = false
 var destCompletedLoads = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed Loads');
 destCompletedLoads.getRange(destCompletedLoads.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
  // Clear content
 var rangeToClear = sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 9, 1, 7);
 rangeToClear.clearContent();
  // Clear U
 sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 21).setValue(false);
  // Clear content in column T (index 20) regardless of checkbox status
 sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 20).clearContent();
}



function sendEmailOnEdit(e) {
 const sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();  // <-- Changed this line...
  if (sheetName === "Washouts") {  // <-- ...and this line.
   var range = e.range;
   var editedValue = range.getValue();


   // Check if any text (non-empty) is entered
   if (editedValue !== "") {
     // Tailor message
     var message = 'Text entered in the Washouts sheet: ' + editedValue;
     var subject = 'message body alert';


     // Email entry
     var recipientEmail = 'myemailaddyhere';


     // Send the email
     MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message);
   }
 }
}

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

REFERENCES:

Event Objects
Simple Trigger Restriction


Feel free to try it on your end and let me know how it turns out.
